# Android Studio Emulator wont start

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

So everything was working fine, today I opened android studio and try to run the emulator, and it wont start. I will provide the errors in an image bellow.
I tried wiping the emulators data , and disabled the antivirus, I tried new device...
Please help I need it :(

[ERRORS OF EMULATOR PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqHDx.jpg)

11:45 AM    Gradle sync started

11:45 AM    Gradle sync finished in 2 s 250 ms (from cached state)

11:46 AM    Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project D:\AndroidStudioProjects\AudioVideo

11:47 AM    Gradle build finished in 47 s 998 ms

11:47 AM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\AndroidStudioProjects\AudioVideo

11:47 AM    Gradle build finished in 20 s 141 ms

11:48 AM    Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: C:\Users\User.android\emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

11:48 AM    Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554

11:48 AM    Emulator: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

11:48 AM    Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

11:48 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

11:49 AM    Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project D:\AndroidStudioProjects\AudioVideo

11:49 AM    Gradle build finished in 5 s 906 ms

Comment: Have you installed intel HAXM

Comment: @FlyingDutchman yes i have it

Answer (score 1):

**Possible solutions**

1. Invalidate/Restart Android studio
2. Open AVD Manager select you emulator and wipe Data from the dropdown
3. Installing Intel latest Intel [HAXM](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases)
4. or delete current emulator and install new one

Answer (score 0):

I want to say, that any possible solution did not work for me, I lost 4 hours working on that. I quit and installed Genymotion , I can tell that it runned smoother than the android emulator.